How to get datatransfer text from handleDrop event on draftjs editor?
I m trying to implement drag and drop a text to react-wysiwyg editor, but on droppng over the editor , not able to achieve the dataTransfer text.
The text to be dragged
<div onDragStart={(e) => {
                  
                  e.dataTransfer.setData(
                    'text',
                   value
                  );
                }}
>{value}</div>

the handleDrop has got 3 arguments, selection, dataTransfer, isInternal
I wanted to do dataTransfer.getData('text') , but throwing error ,
Uncaught TypeError: dataTransfer.getData is not a function
    at Object.handleDropDirect [as handleDrop]

I need to get the data that I have dragged , anything wrong on onDragStart event function?
